# matcher.groupCount() always returns 1

Tags: regular-expressions

I try to extract all mergefields out of an email template, but my matcher just finds the first one. groupCount is always 1. Im new to salesforce. Please help.

```
    pattern mrgflds = pattern.compile ('\\{([^}]*)\\}');
    matcher srchflds = mrgflds.matcher(body);
    srchflds.find();
    Integer cnt = srchflds.groupCount();
    System.debug(srchflds.groupCount());

    for (integer i=0;i<cnt;i++){
        if(srchflds.find()) {
        System.debug(srchflds.group(i));
        }
    }
```

body is this mailbody:

> Guten Tag {!Contact.Salutation} {!Contact.LastName},
>
> Wie vereinbart, sende ich Ihnen hiermit Ihr persönliches Angebot zu.
>
> Sollten Sie noch Fragen zu unserem Angebot oder zu unseren
>   Dienstleistungen haben, zögern Sie bitte nicht, mich jederzeit zu
>   kontaktieren. Ich bin zu diesem Thema Ihre persönliche
>   Ansprechpartnerin. Sie erreichen mich telefonisch unter {!User.Phone}
>   oder per E-Mail unter {!User.Email}.
>
> Wir freuen uns auf Ihre zeitnahe Rückmeldung.
>
> Mit herzlichen Grüßen  {!User.FirstName} {!User.LastName}

Answer (score 3):

The matcher and pattern classes have always stretched my brain a bit too far.  Fortunately, I've done this before and the following worked for me.  Note my pattern may be different than yours.  The gist is the `matcher.find()` method returns true if the pattern is found, and you can get the matched string with the `matcher.group()` call.  I couldn't tell you what exactly `matcher.groupCount()` returns, but if you keep looping until find() returns false and calling group() to get the string, you'll get all your merge fields.

```
Pattern mergeFieldPattern = Pattern.compile('\\{![\\w\\.]*\\}');
Matcher matcher = mergeFieldPattern.matcher(body);
Set<String> referencedMergeFieldsSet = new Set<String>();
while(matcher.find()) {
  referencedMergeFieldsSet.add(matcher.group());
}
```